# Cocoapod is giving error with pod install and not generating xcworkspace

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

I am using the Xcode 7.2 with CocoaPods 0.37.2.

I am trying to install a plugin through CocoaPods and its giving me the below error and its not generating the xcworkspace too.

I have gone through some links and they suggested to update the xcodeproject through the below command. Is this the right way? does this have any kind of effect on my already built product?

```
ruby[2047:53486] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-   9548/IDEFoundation/Initialization/IDEInitialization.m:590
Details:  Assertion failed: _initializationCompletedSuccessfully
Function: BOOL IDEIsInitializedForUserInteraction()
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fb7c3087460>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
0  0x0000000110a35f7f -[DVTAssertionHandler  handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:argum ents:] (in DVTFoundation)
1  0x0000000110a3570c _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
2  0x0000000110a35978 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
3  0x0000000110a358da _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
4  0x0000000111e4654d IDEIsInitializedForUserInteraction (in IDEFoundation)
5  0x0000000114abc631 +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:readOnly:] (in DevToolsCore)
6  0x0000000114abe1b6 +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:] (in DevToolsCore)
7  0x00007fff85d08f44 ffi_call_unix64 (in libffi.dylib)
Abort trap: 6
```

I tried below command first however that did not work

> sudo xcode-select -r

Some people are suggesting to update through this

> "gem install xcodeproj -v 0.24.3"
>   What does it do?

Comment: @KiritModi...what is that link???I have got cocoa pods for many months...it was working well, now its working weird...and you are giving me procedure to install it.. Weird

Comment: Im facing same issue, did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete each instance of the cocoapod and then install 0.38.0 to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo gem install cocoapods` Or `sudo gem update cocoapods`

then Run `pod install`

in my case its resolved my issue.